# sshfs mounts with user privileges but for umount I need root. why? how?

Tags: fstab, sshfs

I'm trying to unmount from nautilus, the directory created by sshfs, but I get this error:

```
Unable to unmount dir
umount: /home/user/dir  is not in the fstab (and you are not root)
```

I'm not getting why is this happening.
How can I unmount sshfs without sudo?

Any enlightenment will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open a terminal window, and type

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mount
```

Comment: works like a charm in Ubuntu 16.04!